# WPF mvvm textbox won't update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, textbox

I'm trying to empty/fill a textbox in WPF mmvm. I created a small form and if you press a button the items from the textboxes are saved in an object category. After I created the "category" the name of each created category will be put in a combobox. Now what I want to do is empty the textboxes after I created the "category" or if I click on a category name in de combobox is display the information in the textboxes.

I got the part of saveing the category working and also the part that if I select an item from the combobox I get an notification.

But when I change the varriable in my code it won't update it in the view.
I connected my Viewmodel and view in a resource.xaml file:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CategoryViewModel}">
    <vw:CategoryView />
</DataTemplate>
```

My ModelView:

```
class CategoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string Title, Description, Colour;


    public string title
    {
        get { return Title; }
        set
        {
            Title = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("title");
        }
    }


    public string description { get { return Description; } set { Description = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("description"); } }
    public string colour { get { return Colour; } set { Colour = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("colour"); } }
    //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> category = new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>();

    private CategoryModel selectedItem = new CategoryModel();

    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Category
    {
        get {
            return category; 
        }
        set { 
            category = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Category"); 
        }
    }
    public CategoryModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { 
            return selectedItem; 
        }
        set { 
            selectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            ChangeCategoryInfo();
        }
    }

    public CategoryViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ICommand btnSaveCategory
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand<string>(BtnSaveCategory); }
    }

    public void BtnSaveCategory(object param)
    {
        Category.Add(new CategoryModel(title, description, colour));
    }

    private void ChangeCategoryInfo()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedd;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChangedd != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChangedd(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            PropertyChangedd(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
        }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="IsalaIndoorNavCreator.Views.CategoryView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="219.831" Height="440">
<Grid Margin="0,0,10,0">
    <Label Content="Naam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboCategorys" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="84,9,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="120" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Category}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"            
        >
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbCategoryName" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="23" 
             Margin="88,36,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="115" 
             Text="{Binding Path=title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             />
    <Label Content="Beschrijving" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Kleur" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="23"
        Margin="94,200,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="109"
        Text="{Binding Path=colour, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        />
    <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0808" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Label Content="Afbeelding" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Selecteer afbeelding" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="103,262,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="../Resources/Placeholder.png"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnSaveCategory" 
            Content="Opslaan" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="128,381,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" 
            Height="49" 
            Command="{Binding btnSaveCategory}"
            />
    <TextBox 
        x:Name="txtCategoryDescription" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="116" 
        Margin="88,64,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="115"
        Text="{Binding Path=description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        />

</Grid>
```

My Model:

```
class CategoryModel : BaseModel
{
    private string name, description, colour;

    public string Colour 
    { 
        get{ 
            return colour; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (colour != value)
            {
                colour = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Colour");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Name 
    {
        get{ 
            return name; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        } 
    }
    public string Description 
    { 
        get { 
            return description; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (description != value)
            {
                description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        } 
    }
    public List<InterestingModel> iMList = new List<InterestingModel>();

    public CategoryModel()
    {

    }

    public CategoryModel(string name, string description, string colour)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public void AddInterestingModel(InterestingModel IM)
    {
        iMList.Add(IM);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you implemented the members for `INotifyPropertyChanged` but didn't actually add the interface to your class signature.  Is it implemented by `BaseModel`?  If not, you need to add it to the signature.  If so, the event in your subclass may be hiding the event in the base class that's actually bound to the interface member, in which case WPF may be listening to a different event than the one you're publishing.

Comment: I had forfotten to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in the viewmodel hehe thanks ;)

Comment: I see you updated the class signature in your post.  Are you still having the problem?

Comment: No it's working now :)